# How to track keypress while code does other stuff too?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a script that writes stuff in game chat depending on what happens. I want to track if my chat is already open or not when it's time for the script to write the message, so it knows whether it needs to open the chat box or not. I would track it by tracking how many times I've pressed enter (even = closed, odd = open). I just don't know how to keep track of it while the code is also doing checks for what's happening. I tried looking into asyncio (I imagine that's what would be used) with the keyboard.wait() function but I can't figure it out, any help would be appreciated!

```
while True:
    (get data from API)
    if kills/deaths changed:
          choose random message from list and type it in chat
    sleep(1)
```

the problem is if I have opened the chat myself, the script will close it and start spamming my skills while it tries to type the message (since to type the message i need to press enter, but if its already open it just closes)

Basically I'm just running a while True loop while doing the checks, sleeping for 1 second between loops. Need some way to accurately track the amount of times enter has been pressed while the code is doing other stuff too.

Comment: You need to tell us what is the interface for your game. Is it the terminal, using "input"? Or do you modify terminal aprameters? Or is it tkinter? or is it gtk ?or is it pygame?

Comment: Also, supplying a minimal reproducible example of your issue:  a complete script that could only display your box, as you call it, would make it _a lot_ easier to help. (== "possible")

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it really clear but it's not my game but League of Legends. It uses API to check kills/deaths then compares to what it was before, if it changed, open chat, type message, send message. I don't really know how to use this site but I try to type how the code works as pseudocode here.